# How to create loading in Unity until load information?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

hi,i found a code for loading scene in unity3D, I want to take when data via PHP (through WWW), Loading displayed, please help me.

Also, how to recognize and change the keyboard language for Android Device?

```
void Update(){
 if (loadScene == false)
            {
                loadScene = true;

                loadingText.text = "Is loading your information...";

                StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene());
            }

            if (loadScene == true)
            {

                loadingText.color = new Color(loadingText.color.r, loadingText.color.g, loadingText.color.b, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));

            }
        }
}

void Start(){
StartCoroutine(rankGet());

}
IEnumerator LoadNewScene() {


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);


        AsyncOperation async = Application.LoadLevelAsync(scene);


        while (!async.isDone) {
            yield return null;
        }

    }

IEnumerator rankGet()
    {
        txtUsername.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("username");
        WWW connection = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1/scoregame/userscorerank.php?uss=" + txtUsername.text);

        yield return (connection);
        if (connection.text == "401")
        {
            //Debug.Log("username do not exits!");
        }
        else
        {
            ranktxt.text = connection.text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use [Async operation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html) for any other purpose then loading new scene, is to

> write your own method that produces an IEnumerable instance.

As described [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/170089/using-asyncoperation-for-our-own-services.html) by msknapp user.

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerable coroutineFunction()
{

    while (!doneYourPersistentProcess())
    // ... wait for it ...
    yield return "";
    // now it is done.
    doPostProcessing();

}

public void doPostProcessing()
{
    // Loading progressbar here
}

public void Update()
{
    if (userStartsPersistentProcess())
        StartCoroutine(coroutineFunction());

}

public bool userStartsPersistentProcess()
{
    // your code here.
}

public bool doneYourPersistentProcess()
{
    // your code here.
}
```

And the last step is to prepare graphic for progress bar.
The easiest way is to change *Fill Amount* value in the Image object, with properties as shown below:
[image]